# error With changing x and y positions of movieclip using array

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, movieclip

I'm trying to create a program using Action Script 3.0 where I click an element, click on another element, the first element goes to the second element.

This is My code:

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.SimpleButton;
import  flash.display.MovieClip;
import  flash.events.MouseEvent;

stop();

var Plchange:MovieClip;
var As:Array = new Array(A1,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7,A8,A9);
var Bs:Array = new Array(B1,B2,B3,B4,B5,B6,B7,B8,B9);
var Cs:Array =new Array(C1,C2,C3,C4,C5,C6,C7,C8,C9,C10,C11,C12);
var Cs1:Array=new Array(C13,C14,C15,C16,C17,C18,C19,C20,C21,C22,C23,C24);

for ( var i:int =0; i<=8 ;i++)
{   
As[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function(me:MouseEvent):void{ gotoPlace(me, As[i])});
Bs[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function(me:MouseEvent):void{ gotoPlace(me, Bs[i])});


}
for ( var Y:int =0; i<=12 ;Y++)
{   
Cs[Y].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function(me:MouseEvent):void{ Set(me, Cs[Y])});
Cs1[Y].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function(me:MouseEvent):void{ Set(me,      Cs1[Y])});
}
function gotoPlace(event:MouseEvent, boing:MovieClip)
{
boing = Plchange;
}
function Set(event:MouseEvent, clip:MovieClip)
{
Plchange.x = clip.x;
Plchange.y = clip.y;
}
```

I'm getting an error:

> TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.
>   at NineMen_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()

where am I going wrong? Please tell me.

Comment: Are A1,A2,A3... MovieClip instance? Usually instance variable and function start lower-case character, class name starts upper-case character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, in `gotoPlace` you should type `Plchange = boing;` not vice versa. And second, you have to check if `Plchange` is assigned a value within function `Set()`. Like this:

```
var Plchange:MovieClip=null;
function gotoPlace(event:MouseEvent, boing:MovieClip)
{
    Plchange = boing;
}
function Set(event:MouseEvent, clip:MovieClip)
{
    if (!Plchange) return; // Plchange is not assigned
    Plchange.x = clip.x;
    Plchange.y = clip.y;
}
```